# Visual Web Developer 2010 - VB.Net xml comment shortcut

Tags: vb.net, visual-web-developer, xml-comments

Hopefully a question with a very quick and simple answer; In previous versions of Visual Studio and Visual Web Developer I've been able to type 3 apostrophe's (i.e ''') on the line before a function that results in the auto generated comment like:

```
  ''' <summary>
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="sender"></param>
  ''' <param name="e"></param>
  ''' <remarks></remarks>
```

Doing this in 2010 doesn't seem to have the same effect, I've tried hunting on Google but with no joy, is this shortcut still available? Has it Changed to something else?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: It's working properly for me (in C#, where we comment using slashes). I can type `///` to trigger the summary block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the case where this didn't work for me in VS2010 in VB either. My problem was that in the project properties, on the Compile tab. 'Generate XML documentation file' was unchecked. I checked it and now the auto comment tags work again.

Comment: Great thanks Peter, I've actually reverted back to 2008 as I couldn't see any great benefit for using 2010 instead (the comment shortcut being one of the many things that annoyed me about 2010). Maybe I'll try again at some point in the future and knowing this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that shortcut still exists, but the next best thing would be to create a custom shortcut that achieves the same purpose.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zwses53.aspx

The link also details how to import shortcuts, not sure if its backwards compatible, but it might be worth giving a go by pointing it at whatever previous version you used.

Comment: Thanks for the link, would I be able to set this up to automatically generate the param tags for all parameters and return tag etc?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but it states "In the list, select the command you want to assign to a shortcut key combination." therefore I would assume that keyboard shortcuts worked similarly in previous versions, so if you went through the configuration there you might be able to find the right command along with any required parameters to generate your commenting.

Comment: Thanks Njak, noticed that after I'd posted that comment, looking into it now.